# Qty problem for bundle product Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product, bundle, qty, qty-increment

[image]I have one bundle product, and in that product default quantity is 1

But when am trying to add that product in cart getting this error

> This product is available for purchase in increments of 10 only

in

> app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php

Does anyone know what can be wrong here??
Many thanks

Comment: Navigate to Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory->Product Stock Options. See if qty increments is enabled. Please check and let know

Comment: yes its enabled

Comment: Please input the Qty Increments input there. If it is 10, the quantity increment will be applied for all products so please do check it and let know

Comment: Can you the screencast, where I need to add qty?

Comment: In the image qty increment seems to be disabled

Comment: yes its disable